# How can I insert a sequential number into a field using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code that I am using to put data into a relational table using Entity Framework:

```
    public IList<Objective> createObjectives()
    {
        var objectiveNames = new[]
        {
            "Objective 1",
            "Objective 2",
            "Objective 3",
            "Objective 4",
            "Objective 5",
            "Objective 6",
            "Objective 7",
            "Objective 8"
        };
        var objectives = objectiveNames.Select(o => new Objective
        {
            ObjectiveSeq = ??,
            Name = o,
            Description = o + " Description",
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
        }
        );
        return objectives.ToList();
    }
```

I have a new field in my table name ObjectiveSeq. How can I modify my LINQ to insert a sequential number in that field starting from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an overload to the `Select` function. You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/bb534869.aspx).

```
Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>)
```

Take a look at the sample shown in the page.

```
 string[] fruits = { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", "passionfruit", "grape" };

 var query = fruits.Select((fruit, index) => new { index, str = fruit });

 foreach (var obj in query)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
 }
```

You can see that we are using `(fruit, index)`. You are selecting both the element and an index.

The output will be

```
{ index = 0, str = apple }
{ index = 1, str = banana }
{ index = 2, str = mango }
{ index = 3, str = orange }
{ index = 4, str = passionfruit }
{ index = 5, str = grape }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var objectives = objectiveNames.Select((o, index) => new Objective
        {
            ObjectiveSeq = index,
            Name = o,
            Description = o + " Description",
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
        }
        );
```